# Is it possible to visit nodes in Python AST with ast.NodeVisitor twice or change order of traversal?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

NodeVisitor traverses the AST depth-first and visits each node only once, on enter. Therefore it's problematic to do something serious with it. Is it possible to change its default behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. You should write your own visitor. Recursively visiting all nodes is fairly simple, so if the ast module stuff doesn't do it for you (and there is nothing in the module to do what you want, in this case), it isn't that bad to do it yourself.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe somebody will be interested in some sketched out example, how to do what was proposed by DSblizzard, so hear is my example:

```
import ast

class RecursiveVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    """ example recursive visitor """

    def recursive(func):
        """ decorator to make visitor work recursive """
        def wrapper(self,node):
            func(self,node)
            for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
                self.visit(child)
        return wrapper

    @recursive
    def visit_Assign(self,node):
        """ visit a Assign node and visits it recursively"""
        print(type(node).__name__)

    @recursive
    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        """ visit a BinOp node and visits it recursively"""
        print(type(node).__name__)

    @recursive
    def visit_Call(self,node):
        """ visit a Call node and visits it recursively"""
        print(type(node).__name__)

    @recursive
    def visit_Lambda(self,node):
        """ visit a Function node """
        print(type(node).__name__)

    @recursive
    def visit_FunctionDef(self,node):
        """ visit a Function node and visits it recursively"""
        print(type(node).__name__)

    @recursive
    def visit_Module(self,node):
        """ visit a Module node and the visits recursively"""
        pass

    def generic_visit(self,node):
        pass

class SimpleVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    """ simple visitor for comparison """

    def recursive(func):
        """ decorator to make visitor work recursive """
        def wrapper(self,node):
            func(self,node)
            for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
                self.visit(child)
        return wrapper

    def visit_Assign(self,node):
        """ visit a Assign node """
        print(type(node).__name__)

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        """ visit a BinOp node """
        print(type(node).__name__)

    def visit_Call(self,node):
        """ visit a Call node """
        print(type(node).__name__)

    def visit_Lambda(self,node):
        """ visit a Function node """
        print(type(node).__name__)

    def visit_FunctionDef(self,node):
        """ visit a Function node """
        print(type(node).__name__)

    @recursive
    def visit_Module(self,node):
        """ visit a Module node and the visits recursively, otherwise you
        wouldn't see anything here"""
        pass

    def generic_visit(self,node):
        pass

# usage example
a = """
b= lambda x: x*5 +5
def hhh(u):
    b=19
    return u*b
m=hhh(9*4+5)
"""

recursive_visitor = RecursiveVisitor()
simple_visitor = SimpleVisitor()
tree = ast.parse(a)
print('\nvisit recursive\n')
recursive_visitor.visit(tree)
print('\nvisit simple\n')
simple_visitor.visit(tree)
```

Hope somebody may find it useful.

Comment: Your code saved my time. Thank you. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53000/Disable-inspections-in-docstrings#focus=Comments-27-6455616.0-0